# Using PHP to output JSON data, and I get white screen

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, phpmyadmin

I'm having a problem using JSON in a PHP file for Android Studio. The thing is, when I run my PHP file on my server it stays on a white screen, but if I only want to show the `'idActividad'` it shows the info, however when I add the `'Actividad'` field it stays on white - what could be causing this?

Here is the code in question:

```
<?php
include('Conexion.php');

$respuesta = array();
$respuesta["frutas"] = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablaactividad";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    // Array temporal para crear una sola categoría

    $tmp = array();
    $tmp["id"] = $row["idActividad"];
    $tmp["nombre"] = $row["Actividad"];

    // Push categoría a final json array

    array_push($respuesta["frutas"], $tmp);
}

// Mantener el encabezado de respuesta a json

header('Content-Type: application/json');

// Escuchando el resultado de json

echo json_encode($respuesta);
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: You're probably getting an error, so it's worth checking your error log for any details.

Comment: Edit your code and add your code inside coding tags.

Comment: i already did it

Comment: @tadman, i checked my error_log and its clean

Comment: Try to print value of $row["Actividad"] inside while loop.

Comment: do have charset=utf8 in your Conexion.php ?

Comment: @BarclickFloresVelasquez i dont , but my tables are using that format. How do i add it ?

Comment: mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8"); add it in your Conexion.php.

Comment: Thanks @BarclickFloresVelasquez problem solved.

Comment: @BarclickFloresVelasquez the results that i'm having the special characters  are appearing like ""ENSE\u00d1ANZA"  do i need to add the charset on the listing php as well?

Comment: good to hear that. yes just try to add it.